# Content Porter doesn't show the 'Add' Server Button

Tags: content-porter-2013

I've just installed content porter (2013 sp1) and I cannot add new servers to my environment, the button to 'add' seems to me missing:

[image: SDL Tridion Content Porter 2013]

Answer (score 4):

It seems there is a problem in the UI of the content porter application, to ensure the button can be found go into:

- Control Panel > Appearance and personalization > Display

and set the font size to '**Smaller 100% (default)**'.

After doing so you will need to reboot your machine for the changes to take effect.

Comment: Had you use CP on this environment earlier?
I mean this problem is introduced in 2013 SP1 only?

Comment: no i hadn't used any other version of content porter, but i suspect all versions are effected with the same UI issues.

Comment: We've already test this. This defect was involved only in 2013 SP1. This will be fixed in next versions.

Comment: I've seen this in SDL 2013 as well.